# Divergence of a vector field defined by a single variable only

Tags: vectors, divergence-operator

I understand how to take the divergence of a vector field defined by (x,y,z) but how can one take the divergence for the following:

$$\bar F = \bar a \times \bar r$$where $\bar a$ is a constant vector and $\bar r$ is $(bcos(\theta) , bsin(\theta) , c\theta)$, with b and c being positive constants and $\theta$ taking values between 0 to $\frac{5\pi}{2}$.

I have worked out the cross product to be 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_2c\theta - a_3b\sin(\theta)\\
a_3bcos(\theta) - a_1c\theta\\
a_1bsin(\theta) - a_2bcos(\theta)\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

if we let $\bar a = (a_1,a_2,a_3)$

However, I am not sure how to proceed after this to work out the divergence, since there is no x, y, or z (apparently the answer turns out to be 0).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you using cylindrical or spherical coordinates?

Comment: @G. Sassatelli I did not parametrise the field to get $\bar r$, $\bar r$ was simply stated in the question to be this, whereby $\bar r$ defines the position vectors of a curve $C_1$ in cartesian coordinates. Hence I am afraid I'm not sure which coordinates were used.

Answer (score 0):

$\nabla \cdot (\overrightarrow{a}\times\overrightarrow{r})=\overrightarrow{r}\cdot (\nabla\times\overrightarrow{a})-\overrightarrow{a}\cdot(\nabla\times\overrightarrow{r})=-\overrightarrow{a}\cdot(\nabla\times\overrightarrow{r})$

for $\overrightarrow{r}$, $x=b\cos\theta, y=b\sin\theta, z=c\theta$, can be reparameterized as :

$x=b\cos(\cfrac{z}{c})$

$y=b\sin(\cfrac{z}{c})$

$z=z$

$\nabla \times\overrightarrow{r}=-\cfrac{b}{c}\Big(\cos(\cfrac{z}{c})\mathbf{i}+\sin(\cfrac{z}{c})\mathbf{j}\Big)$

Comment: thank you for your answer, however, using your parametrisation: $\bar r = (bcos(\frac{z}{c}) , bsin(\frac{z}{c}) , z)$, I can't get the divergence to equal 0? Also the curl cannot equal 0 as it was stated that this vector field is not conservative

Comment: The curl of $\overrightarrow{r}$ is not 0. See the last line in my post. Curl of $\overrightarrow{a}$ is 0(vector) as it's a constant.

Comment: yes sorry I did not mean that I think the curl of $\bar r$ is 0, I was just saying that from your working, I could not get the divergence to equal 0. I only added the curl of $\bar r$ cannot equal 0 as a side note.